# PayPal REST API - Deactivate German Direct Debit

Tags: api, rest, paypal, credit-card

at the moment I work on a festival page. There you can buy a ticket over PayPal Account and Creditcard. But I'm from Germany and there is also the "Direct Debit" (Lastschrift) available, I don't want this. I searched the www about to deactivate that but I can't find any help :(.

In Use: PHP REST API

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if you are passing **LOCALECODE=DE** (or are in Germany) this option will always be available. The only payment options you can limit inside your PayPal account are eCheck and giropay.